# CSS Positioning - Best Way To Position

Tags: css

Whats' the best way to position? Float, Relative, Absolute?

Lets say I want to position something like this:

[image]

How do I position something like this and what's the best way to do it?
Float, Relative, Absolute?

Comment: Answer: it depends. Ask a general question, get a general answer. We need more specifics, for example: is this for dynamic content you have no control over or is it static content you can fine-tune?

Comment: And where's _your_ code?

Comment: Your question might not be suited for this site. It's rather open-ended since you're asking for the 'best' way when there isn't a single, definitive answer. Also, it would have been nice to see some of your code trying the different ways, with questions addressing specific areas you got stuck.

Comment: Where is the humor in the position bit?

Comment: You should read this book: http://www.amazon.com/CSS-Missing-David-Sawyer-McFarland/dp/0596802447 It has great tips on layout.

Comment: @Scott Simpson Thank you for the book suggestion sounds like an excellent book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `fluid layout`, use `floats`.

Positioning elements `relative/absolute` causes them to display as `inline` therefore a `height/width` is required and they then become `non-fluid`.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a div that acts as a container

Then create three more divs one for the right side and two for the left side.

I have created a jSfiddle file for you to reference. Something quick I created

http://jsfiddle.net/wSp7F/

*It all depends on which type of layout you are going for. Responsive, Fluid or Fixed.*

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="rightside">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
<div class="leftside">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>

<div class="leftside">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>

</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#container {width:500px;position:relative;overflow:Hidden;outline:1px solid red}

.leftside {float:left;width:225px;margin:0 0 5px 0}
#rightside {float:right;width:200px}

.leftside,#rightside {outline:1px solid black;padding:5px}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single best way, but here's how I'd do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wuj35/

### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div3">div 3</div> 
    <div id="div1">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">div 2</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#wrapper{
    width:450px;
}

#div1,
#div2,
#div3{
    float:left;
    margin:1em;
    padding:1em;
    border:5px solid #000;
    border-radius:8px;
}

#div1, 
#div2{
    width:150px;
    height:75px;
}

#div2{
    clear:left;
}

#div3{
    float:right;
    width:150px;
    height:225px;
}
```